# What is the difference between ADD UNIQUE and ADD CONSTRAINT x UNIQUE

Tags: sql-server, unique-constraint

whats is the difference between these two statements to make a Column Unique?

```
ALTER TABLE [TABLE]
ADD CONSTRAINT [Cons_name] UNIQUE (Columname);

ALTER TABLE [TABLE]
ADD UNIQUE (Columname);
```

Also, there is any difference when I want to add a composite unique as (column1, column2,...)?

Comment: If you explicitly give a name for the constraint, it will be named like that. If you don't the DBMS creates some other name. That applies to any count of columns in the constraint.

Comment: I suggest one explicitly name constraints. This facilitates subsequent DDL operations and makes it easier to understand it's purpose with good naming conversion (e.g. `UQ_TableName_ColumnName`).

Comment: Can't agree more with defining the name of the constraints. Not doing so can make for pains when using multiple environments, as they end up with different names, and more meaningful errors.

Comment: ok, so the only difference is the ability to specify a name?